# If you live far away from popular DNS servers, is it still recommended to use them?

Tags: dns, latency

My friend suggested that I should use one of popular DNS servers like Google. Since there are no nearby DNS servers from where I live, I thought I would do a DNS benchmark and to my surprise, According to the result, my default/ISP DNS servers are slightly faster than other DNS servers by 20-30%

With all that said, does it still NOT make sense to switch?

Comment: Just curious...did you check OpenDNS?

Comment: Yes. I even checked onedotone (i think this is what it is called). Sadly none of well known dns servers seem to outperform my ISP’s.

Comment: Well, unless you don't mind your ISP possibly tracking your online movements, I'd go ahead and stick with your ISP's DNS servers.

Comment: Well that’s hardly my concern. I am purely for performance wise here.

Comment: Right, got sidetracked. Then I'd say you've answered your own question. You've apparently done your own testing and your ISP's DNS servers seem to outperform the others, so unless you can find another that surpasses your ISP's, I'd stick with the ISP. The only reason I can think of to switch is if you do mind your ISP tracking your movements.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1130932/does-using-opendns-or-google-dns-affect-anything-about-security-or-gaming-speed/1130940#1130940

Answer (score 1):

I'll do you one better... Why not host your own internal DNS server?

If you have a spare old PC, you can install your favourite version of Linux (I use Debian and Ubuntu), and they will likely have a guide to create a DNS server using BIND software. It can cache the responses, making subsequent requests faster. If it doesn't have the answer, it can check with a "forwarding DNS server" (i.e. your ISP, or Google DNS, or OpenDNS, etc) to get the answer, and save it.